# Convert UIView transform to CALayer

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiview, transform, calayer

I have UIView which I apply transform to. I'm trying to understand how to fetch the **rotation** of the UIView and apply it to the **CALayer**. If I'm printing the UIView transform I get this:

```
CGAffineTransform(a: 0.977750351365919, b: -0.209771900891948, c: 0.209771900891948, d: 0.977750351365919, tx: 0.0, ty: 0.0)
```

Though, I can't understand how to apply the **rotation** transform the the CALayer.

```
layer.transform
```

expecting to get `CATransform3D`.

Comment: A view _is_ a layer. Well, it has a layer. So if you've applied a transform to the UIView, you've applied that transform to the view's layer as well. So what's the problem? The transform is already applied.

Comment: @matt , I'm creating new CALayer, not the same one on the UIView

Comment: @matt , and i need to fetch on the rotation part as well

Comment: Can you show some actual code you've tried, or is this some sort of deep dark secret?

Comment: @matt Haha no secrets, i usually share it, But this time this is nothing but couple lines of code which doing nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you expect to have happen does happen. I ran this code:

```
self.v.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.5)
```

And later this code:

```
let t = self.v.layer.transform
print(t)
```

It printed this:

> `CATransform3D(m11: 0.877582561890373, m12: 0.479425538604203, m13: 0.0, m14: 0.0, m21: -0.479425538604203, m22: 0.877582561890373, m23: 0.0, m24: 0.0, m31: 0.0, m32: 0.0, m33: 1.0, m34: 0.0, m41: 0.0, m42: 0.0, m43: 0.0, m44: 1.0)`

That is indeed the CATransform3D form of the affine transform originally applied to the view. You could now apply this same transform to some other layer if desired.

Note too that in the special case where the transform to be applied to the layer is an affine transform, you can apply it directly as an affine transform (using the `setAffineTransform:` method). So there is actually no need to fetch the view's layer's `transform`; you can apply the view's affine transform directly to another layer.

Comment: Oh, Haha! Can't believe i haven't thought about it lol. But how can the rotation applies from all this details ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're now asking. I believe I answered your original question.

Comment: You did answered it(which i'm very thankful on). Tho, i asked as well how i can get the exact *rotation* transform applied to the UIView. CATransform3D containing multiple values. Which one is the rotation one? (I hope i'm being more clear now). Thanks Matt!

Comment: The whole thing is the rotation. If you don't understand what a transform is, read https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH204-CJBECIAD

Comment: All the values are the rotation? some of the might, but i'm pretty sure its presentation of matrix,scale etc etc

Comment: The transform is the mathematical sum of all these things, yes. But it is not nearly as simple as this float for the scale, this other float for the rotation... You may as well ask 'which part of this cake is the sugar'

Comment: @Jef , Thanks Jef. Got it!